# почему получается undefined

Tags: javascript

Создаю простую функцию, для отображения имён 3-х пользователей на странице, но не как не пойму почему получаю `undefined`? Я передаю массив имён в функцию.

```
function loadProfiles(userNames){
    if (userNames.length > 3) {
        let loadingMessage = "This might take a while...";
        console.log(loadingMessage);
    } else {
        let flashMessage = "Loading profiles";
        console.log(flashMessage);
    }
}

console.log(loadProfiles(["user1","user2","user3","user4"]));
```

Comment: А return где? Ваша функция ничего не возвращает

Comment: @stas.t вам правильно комментарий выше подсказывает. Почему вы не прочитали документацию о том, как писать функции на `javascript`?

Comment: Приведите более полный код, где и как используются flashMessage и loadingMessage

Comment: в том и дело что я пока не использую  flashMessage и loadingMessage . весь код состоит из примера выше и файла index.html который вызывает функцию loadProfiles(["user1", "user2", "user3", "user4"]); и передаёт ей массив из имён. разобрался вроде.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В  javascript как и в любом другом языке програмирования функции выполняют прямие действия и побочные.

Прямые это например сложеные двух чисел и возврат результата

```
function sum(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

// в этом случае результат роботы функции можно записывать в переменную
var rez = sum(2,2);
console.log(rez);

// или просто выводить в лог
console.log(sum(1,2));
```

Побочные действия функций это те действия которые они осуществляют с окружением в котором вызваны, например то же сложение но результат записывается в переменную глобальной видимости, а не возвращается в виде результата

```
var rez;

function sum(a, b) {
    rez = a + b;
}

// функция еще не отработала значение `undefined`
console.log(rez);

// функция уже отработала однако видим значение `undefined` потому что функция ничего нам не возвращает
console.log(sum(1, 2));

// видим тройку потому что во время работы функции в предыдущей инструкции она совершила побочное действие над переменной `var rez` присвоив ей сумму передаваемых параметров
console.log(rez);
```

Стоит отметить что в javascript функции всегда что то возвращают, если в теле инструкция `return` не задана явно то возвращаемое значение `undefined`

Эти вещи могуть быть комбинированы, например

```
function sum(a, b) {
    console.log('я посчитала');
    return a + b;
}

console.log(sum(1, 2));
```

Тут возврат суммы чисел прямое действие, а вывод сообщения в лог побочное.

Теперь о вашем примере. У вас функция которая выполняет только побочные действия, в данном случае передавая в качестве параметров массив из четырех имен Вы попадаете в блок

```
if (userNames.length > 3) {
    let loadingMessage = "This might take a while...";
    console.log(loadingMessage);
}
```

И собственно получаете это сообщение в лог, однако так как Вы к функции обращаетесь тоже через `console.log` то второй строкой он выводит `undefined` так как функция ничего не возвращает.

Перепишите пример так и Вы получите ожидаемый (я надеюсь :) ) результат

```
function loadProfiles(userNames){
    if (userNames.length > 3) {
        let loadingMessage = "This might take a while...";
        console.log(loadingMessage);
    } else {
        let flashMessage = "Loading profiles";
        console.log(flashMessage);
    }
}

loadProfiles(["user1","user2","user3","user4"]);
```

или так

```
function loadProfiles(userNames) {
    if (userNames.length > 3) {
        let loadingMessage = "This might take a while...";
        return loadingMessage;
    } else {
        let flashMessage = "Loading profiles";
        return flashMessage;
    }
}

console.log(loadProfiles(["user1", "user2", "user3", "user4"]));
```

Comment: благодарю за развёрнутый ответ. как же ты мне помог. спасибо большое!!!